# C# beginner, "tying" a resource to a class object

Tags: c#, image, list, class, resources

If I have a class, `Car`, and I invoke several instances, one being a Jeep for example.
How would I approach tying an image resource I have already created, to this instance?

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name;
    public string Color;
    public int Value;
}

Car Jeep = new Car();
Jeep.Name = "Jeep";
Jeep.Color = "Red";
Jeep.Value = 20000;
//Jeep.image = jeep; <--- Something like this is possible?
```

For example:
`Image jeep = WindowsFormsApplication1.Resource1.image1;`

I would like to be able to do say something like,
`pictureBox1.Image = List[0].image;`

As I will be putting Jeep, Camaro, Mustang etc into a list.

Someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add the `Image` property to the class `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your image field to the Car class the same way that you have Name, Color, and Value defined.  Then you will be able to assign it just like your other variables.

Comment: Forgive my stupdidity, but, I can only add a string integer etc, how would I add "WindowsFormsApplication1.Resource1.image1" as it is not a string. Could you give an example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, exactly.  image1 in your above example is just  an instance of a Class, presumably a Class named Image.  So just like your Class definition says
`public int Value`
you would put 
`public Image image`